# Elasticsearch 7.6 "illegal_argument_exception" mapper [processes.pid] of different type, current_type [text], merged_type [long]

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm loading a document into a new instance of Elasticsearch.  I'm using dynamic mapping and have 'numeric_detection' turned on.

The field that causes the exception is a number...

```
{
  "processes": [
    {
      "pid": 1,
      "user": "root",
      "pr": 20,
...
```

Here is the index mapping...

```
{
  "mapping": {
    "_doc": {
      "dynamic": "true",
      "_meta": {},
      "_source": {
        "includes": [],
        "excludes": []
      },
      "dynamic_date_formats": [
        "strict_date_optional_time",
        "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss Z||yyyy/MM/dd Z"
      ],
      "date_detection": true,
      "numeric_detection": true
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas why I'm getting this exception?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `processes.pid` was already mapped as text. Did you inserted before documents with pid field as string ?

Comment: This was the first document inserted into the index.

Answer (score 0):

This was a problem with my document, not ElasticSearch.  The process that created the document put an empty element in the 'processes' array.  That empty element has 'pid' as a string, while the other elements had 'pid' as numbers.  Hence the exception.